# NSPredicate to query many-to-many relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have two Core Data classes that are related to each other with many-to-many relation. Let the classes be `Item` and `Group`, where `Item.groups` can reference to multiple `Group`, and `Group.items` to multiple `Item` objects.

I am trying to use `NSPredicate` to query all `Item` objects that do not belong to a specific `Group`. Using `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY group == %@", specificGroup]` to query `Item` objects I can get the inverse set of what I want. It has proven hard to accomplish the opposite.

What I have tried and found not working:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE groups == %@", specificGroup] // always returns 0 results
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (ANY groups == %@)", specificGroup] // always returns 0 results
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY groups != %@", specificGroup] // always returns 0 results
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try `@"NOT %@ IN groups", specificGroup`

Comment: Edit: Further testing unfortunately reveals that was not a correct answer. I does return all `Item` objects that belong to any `Group`, but not those that do not belong to any. Also, an `Item` is included in the result as many times as to how many groups it is referencing to.